# Is there any difference between git checkout <branch_name> and git checkout -b <branch_name>

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm very new to git so I'm about to make my fist commit, so for this I have created a branch by typing `git checkout my_branch` .This worked fine. But after I saw in the documentation that It is used `git checkout -b my_branch`

Is there any difference between those?

Comment: `git -b checkout` is short for `git branch` and then `git checkout`but how about excluding the `-b`in `git checkout` Does it have any effect?

Comment: What you might infer from the below answers, but they don't spell out explicitly, is that *if*, as you say, `git checkout my_branch` (with no `-b`) worked, then the branch already existed and what happened may not be what you think happened.  (Due to git being hlepful - in a way that really is useful but isn't easy to explain - the branch might not have existed locally yet, which is what torek's answer draws out in a bit more detail.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
$ git checkout asdfadsf
error: pathspec 'asdfasdf' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

This failed because I *don't* have a branch `asdfasdf`.  Git tried to treat `asdfasdf` as a file name, and I *don't* have a file named `asdfasdf` either.

```
$ git checkout -b asdfasdf
Switched to a new branch 'asdfasdf'
```

This succeeded and created a new branch.

On the other hand, I *don't* have a branch named `maint`, and yet:

```
$ git checkout maint
Branch 'maint' set up to track remote branch 'maint' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'maint'
```

This, too, created a *new* branch, `maint`.  But notice how it looks different.  It still says `Switched to a new branch`, but *first* it says `Branch 'maint' set up to track remote branch 'maint' from 'origin'.`

The reasoning behind this is a little complicated, but it boils down to this:

- *Without* `-b`, if you ask for a branch that you don't have, Git will try some alternatives.  Some of them may work!  When it works the way `maint` did here, the new branch has an *upstream* set already.
- *With* `-b`, Git will just *create* the branch, no questions asked (provided that creating a new branch is possible).  The new branch *won't* be set up with an upstream.  If you already have the branch, you get an error.

If you *want* a branch with an upstream set—for instance, if there's an `origin/feature/x123` and you want your own `feature/x123` created to match—you *don't* want the `-b` option, because that won't do the search for an upstream `origin/feature/x123`.  If you *don't* want an upstream set, you *do* want the `-b` option.

(Whether and when you want the upstream set for you is a separate question.  Search StackOverflow for the existing answers.)

Answer (score 0):

when you run with -b you are telling git to create the branch for you. git checkout without -b requires the branch to exist already to work.