# How different is "git checkout -b your-branch-name" from "git checkout branch-name"?

Tags: git, version-control

I recently came across a Git syntax `git checkout -b your-branch-name`. How different is this from `git checkout branch-name`? Please can anyone explain how do the two syntaxes differ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference between git checkout <branch_name> and git checkout -b <branch_name>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55974730/2745495)

Comment: it does thank you. It does not explicitly define the distinct scenarios in the doc.

Answer (score 3):

The `-b` creates a **new** branch and switches to it.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout